# MAGENTO: Reindexing price programmatically

Tags: magento, reindex

I update prices in magento programmatically. How can I reindexing prices after this update. Now I used SSH command:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
```

Comment: What's the problem with that ssh command?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The following will reindex each index.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);
    $process->reindexAll();
}
```

You can also use the Magento collection model to load each index rather than hard coding the id in the for loop.

```
/* @var $indexCollection Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Process_Collection */
$indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
    /* @var $index Mage_Index_Model_Process */
    $index->reindexAll();
}
```

But if you want to reindex just the price the id is 2

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(2);
$process->reindexAll();
```

You could also call the function getProcessByCode as follows:

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
$process->reindexAll();
```

Comment: Glad I could find an answer for you.

Comment: I don't like the '9' in the loop. Do you have an alternative for this?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the loading of index processes via a collection.

Comment: can u explain, what is the problem with reindexing using indexer.php?

Comment: @ThangPham if you are able to run the indexer.php via ssh then use it but if you want to reindex in a model or controller then use the php above.

Answer (score 3):

By using following SSH command you can reindex all the indexes.

```
php shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

But if you want to reindex only catalog_product_price then you can use below code.

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
```

Comment: This is just explaining what he's already doing. The OP wants to know how to do it programatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
php -f indexer.php help
```

You can use this command for all command related to reindex through SSH.

```
php indexer.php -- reindex [process_code]

  e.g: php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
```

Those are via SSH if you like code ways then you have to go through below code:

```
 $indexer = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price')
 $indexer->reindexEverything();
```

or do this :

```
  for ($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++) {  
       $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);  
      $process->reindexAll();  
  }
```

[For More Info](http://www.jyotiranjan.in/blog/reindexing-magento-programmatically/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have flat tables on and wonder why (as I did today) programmatically updated prices are not displaying on the front end no matter how many times you reindex, most probably you need to reindex the product flat AFTER you reindex the prices:

```
php shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_product_price
php shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_product_flat
```

If you do a normal:

```
php shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

Note the order of the reindexing:

```
Category Flat Data index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Flat Data index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog product price index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
...
```

The product flat is indexed BEFORE the prices, there fore the price updates were not updated in the flat tables (i.e. catalog_product_flat_2). Look in the flat tables to make sure your programmatically updated prices are set.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
   namespace Webizon\ApiConnector\Controller\Index;
   class Reindex extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {     
/**
 * @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory
 */
protected $indexerFactory;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Indexer\ConfigInterface
 */
protected $config;
/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $resultLayoutFactory    
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Indexer\ConfigInterface $config
) {     
    $this->indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
    $this->config = $config;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
/**
 * Regenerate full index
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function execute()
{           
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    if(isset($params['run'])){
        if($params['run'] == 'all'){
            $this->reindexAll(); 
        }else{
            $this->reindexOne($params['run']);
        }   
    }           
}
/**
 * Regenerate single index
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Exception
 */
private function reindexOne($indexId){
    $indexer = $this->indexerFactory->create()->load($indexId);
    $indexer->reindexAll();
}
/**
 * Regenerate all index
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Exception
 */
private function reindexAll(){
    foreach (array_keys($this->config->getIndexers()) as $indexerId) {          
        $indexer = $this->indexerFactory->create()->load($indexerId);
        $indexer->reindexAll();            
    }
}
  }
```

http://www.webizon.in/apiconnector/index/reindex/all => to run reindex all

http://www.webizon.in/apiconnector/index/reindex/indexer_id => to run separate reindexing

(Ex: http://www.webizon.in/apiconnector/index/reindex/catalog_product_price) - To run price indexing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with links and source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks